# How to bind two stores to one view in Sencha?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, coverflow

I am trying to build a custom component in Sencha Touch which would display values from two stores. I am trying to build upon Ext.us.Cover which extends from Ext.data.DataView. Since I am a beginner in Sencha, I could use some help on how to accomplish binding two stores to one view.

Here is what I have currently:

```
/**
 * @class Ext.ux.CrossCover
 * @extend Ext.DataView
 *
 * A CrossCover represents two intersecting Cover flows
 * @author Abhishek Mukherjee
*/
Ext.define('Ext.ux.CrossCover',{
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    xtype: 'cover',

    config:{
       /**
         * @cfg {Number} selectedIndex The idx from the Store that will be active first. Only one item can be active at a
         * time
         * @accessor
         * @evented
         */
        selectedIndex: 0,

        /**
         * @cfg {String} itemCls
         * A css class name to be added to each item element.
         */
        itemCls: '',

        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} preventSelectionOnItemTap
         * Prevent selection when item is tapped. This is false by default.
         */
        preventSelectionOnItemTap: false,

        /**
         * @cfg {Number} angle for cover background items
         * This is the angle that not selected items are moved in space.
         */
        angle: 75,

        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} set to true if you want a flat representation. Defaults to false so the
         * coverflow remains 3d.
         */
        flat: false,

        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} preventOrientationChange
         * Prevent attaching refresh method to orientation change event on Ext.Viewport
         */
        preventOrientationChange: false,

        /**
         * @cfg {Ext.data.Store} horizontalStore
         * Store containing data for horizontal cover-flow 
         */
        horizontalStore: '',

        //private
        baseCls: 'ux-cover',
        //private
        itemBaseCls: 'ux-cover-item-inner',
        //private
        scrollable: null,
        //private
        orientationCls: undefined
    },

    offset: 0,
    horizontalOffset: 0,

    //override
    initialize: function(){

        console.log("Called");
        //we need somehow to put the itemCls to the tpl wraper element 
        this.innerItemCls = this.getItemCls();
        if(this.innerItemCls) {
            this.setItemCls(this.innerItemCls+'-wrap');
        }

        this.callParent();
        console.log(this.element.type);
        this.element.on({
            drag: 'onDrag',
            dragstart: 'onDragStart',
            dragend: 'onDragEnd',
            scope: this
        });

        this.on({
            painted: 'onPainted',
            itemtap: 'doItemTap',
            scope: this
        });

        if(!this.getPreventOrientationChange()){
            //subscribe to orientation change on viewport
            Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', this.refresh, this);
        }

        this.setItemTransformation = (this.getFlat())?this.setItemTransformFlat:this.setItemTransform3dVertical;
    },

    getElementConfig: function(){
        console.log("getElementConfig Called");
        return {
            reference: 'element',
            children:[{
                reference: 'innerElement',
                className: 'ux-cover-scroller'
            }]
        };
    },

    applyFlat: function(flat) {
        return (Ext.os.is('Android')? true : flat);
    },

    updateOrientationCls: function(newOrientation, oldOrientation) {
        var baseCls = this.getBaseCls();
        if(this.element && newOrientation != oldOrientation) {
            this.element.removeCls(baseCls+'-'+oldOrientation);
            this.element.addCls(baseCls+'-'+newOrientation);
        }
    },

    applyItemTpl: function(config){
        console.log("applyItemTpl Called");
        if(Ext.isArray(config)){
            config = config.join("");
        }
        return new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="' + this.getItemBaseCls() + ' ' + this.getItemCls() + ' ">'+config+'</div>');
    },

    onPainted: function(){
        this.refresh();
    },

    //private
    getTargetEl: function(){
        console.log("getTargetEl Called");
        return this.innerElement;
    },

    onDragStart: function(){
        console.log("onDragStart Called");
        this.getTargetEl().dom.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0s";
    },

    onDrag: function(e){
        console.log("onDrag Called");
        var curr = this.getOffset(),
            offset,
            ln = this.getViewItems().length,
            selectedIndex,
            delta = (e.deltaY - e.previousDeltaY);

        //slow down on border conditions
        selectedIndex = this.getSelectedIndex();

        if ((selectedIndex === 0 && e.deltaY > 0) || (selectedIndex === ln - 1 && e.deltaY < 0)) {
            delta *= 0.5;
        }

        offset = curr + delta;

        this.setOffset(offset, true);
    },

    onDragEnd: function(){
        console.log("onDragEnd Called");
        var idx = this.getSelectedIndex(),
            y = - (idx * this.gap);
        this.getTargetEl().dom.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0.4s";
        //this.setOffset(x);
        this.applySelectedIndex(idx);
    },

    doItemTap: function(cover, index, item, evt){
        if(!this.getPreventSelectionOnItemTap() && this.getSelectedIndex() !== index){
            this.setSelectedIndex(index);
        }
    },

    getSelectedIndex: function(){
        console.log("getSelectedIndex Called");
        var idx, ln;
        if(this.isRendered()){
            ln = this.getViewItems().length;
            idx = - Math.round(this.getOffset() / this.gap);
            this.selectedIndex = Math.min(Math.max(idx, 0),  ln - 1);
        }
        return this.selectedIndex;
    },

    applySelectedIndex: function(idx){
        console.log("applySelectedINdex Called");
        if(this.isRendered()){
            this.updateOffsetToIdx(idx);
            this.selectWithEvent(this.getStore().getAt(idx));
        }else{
            this.selectedIndex = idx;
        }

        // apply horizontal index 
        this.applySelectedHorizontalIndex(idx);
    },

     applySelectedHorizontalIndex: function(idx){
         console.log("applySelectedHorizontalIndex Called");
        if(this.isRendered()){
            this.updateHorizontalOffsetToIdx(idx);
            this.selectWithEvent(this.getHorizontalStore().data.items[idx]);
        }else{
            this.selectedIndex = idx;
        }
    },

    updateOffsetToIdx: function(idx){
        console.log("updateOffsetToIdx Called");
        var ln = this.getViewItems().length,
            offset;

        idx = Math.min(Math.max(idx, 0), ln - 1);
        offset= -(idx * this.gap);
        this.setOffset(offset);
    },

    updateHorizontalOffsetToIdx: function(idx){
        console.log("updateHorizontalOffsetToIdx Called");
        var ln = this.getHorizontalStore().data.items.length,
            offset;
       // console.log("Number of horizontal items is ")
        idx = Math.min(Math.max(idx, 0), ln - 1);
        offset= -(idx * this.gap);
        this.setHorizontalOffset(offset);
    },
    setOffset: function(offset){
        console.log("setOffset Called");
        // Set offset for the vertical cover
        var items = this.getViewItems(),
            idx = 0,
            l = items.length,
            item;
        this.offset = offset;
        // Changing the translation to Y-axis
        this.getTargetEl().dom.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d( 0," + offset + "px, 0)";
        for(;idx<l;idx++){
            item = Ext.get(items[idx]);
            this.setItemTransformation(item, idx, offset);
        }

    },

     setHorizontalOffset: function(offset){
         console.log("setHorizontalOffset Called");

        // Set offset for the horizontal cover
        var hitems = this.getHorizontalStore().data.items,
            hidx = 0,
            hl = hitems.length,
            hitem;
        console.log("horizontal store items :"+hl);
        this.horizontalOffset = offset;
        // Changing the translation to X-axis
        this.getTargetEl().dom.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d( " + offset + "px, 0, 0)";
        for(;hidx<hl;hidx++){
            hitem =  document.createElement("div"); 
            var newContent = document.createTextNode(hitems[hidx].data.preferredName); 
            hitem.appendChild(newContent); 
            console.log("hitem is"+hitem);
            this.setItemTransform3dHorizontal(hitem, hidx, offset);
        }
    },

    getOffset: function(){
        console.log("getOffset Called");
        return this.offset;
    },

     getHorizontalOffset: function(){
         console.log(" getHorizontaloffset Called");
        return this.horizontalOffset;
    },

    getBaseItemBox: function(containerBox){
        console.log("getBaseItemBox Called");
        var cH = containerBox.height,
            cW = containerBox.width,
            sizeFactor = (cW > cH) ? 0.68 : 0.52,
            h, w;

        h = w = Math.min(containerBox.width, containerBox.height) * sizeFactor;

        return {
            top: (containerBox.height - w) / 2  ,
            height: h * 1.5,
            width: w,
            left: (containerBox.width - w) / 2
        };
    },

    setBoundaries: function(itemBox){
        console.log("setBoundaries Called");
        var w = itemBox.width;
        if(this.getFlat()){
            this.gap = w * 1.1;
            this.threshold = this.gap / 3;
            this.delta = w * 0.2;
        } else {
            this.gap = w / 3;
            this.threshold = this.gap / 2;
            this.delta = w * 0.4;
        }
    },

    setItemTransformation: Ext.emptyFn,

    setItemTransform3dVertical: function(item, idx, offset){
        console.log("type of item is:"+ item.type);
        console.log("Called setItemTransform3dVertical"+offset);
        var x = idx * this.gap,
            ix = x + offset,
            transf = "";
        if(ix < this.threshold && ix >= - this.threshold){
            // Changing the translation to Y-axis
            transf = "translate3d( 0,"+x+"px, 150px)";
            this.selectedIndex = idx;
        }else if(ix > 0){
            // Changing the rotation to x-axis
            transf = "translate3d( 0 ,"+(x+this.delta)+"px, 0 ) rotateX(-"+this.getAngle()+"deg)";
        }else{
            // Changing the rotation to x-axis
            transf = "translate3d( 0, "+(x-this.delta)+"px, 0 ) rotateX("+this.getAngle()+"deg)";
        }
        item.dom.style.webkitTransform = transf;
    },

    setItemTransform3dHorizontal: function(item, idx, offset){
        console.log("Called setItemTransform3dHorizontal"+offset);
        console.log("item receieved::"+item + " idx is "+idx+" offset is "+offset);
        var x = idx * this.gap,
            ix = x + offset,
            transf = "";
        if(ix < this.threshold && ix >= - this.threshold){
            // Changing the translation to X-axis
            transf = "translate3d( "+x+"px, 0, 150px)";
            this.selectedIndex = idx;
        }else if(ix > 0){
            // Changing the rotation to Y-axis
            transf = "translate3d( "+(x+this.delta)+"px, 0 , 0 ) rotateY(-"+this.getAngle()+"deg)";
        }else{
            // Changing the rotation to Y-axis
            transf = "translate3d( "+(x-this.delta)+"px, 0,  0 ) rotateY("+this.getAngle()+"deg)";
        }
        item.style.webkitTransform = transf;
    },

    setItemTransformFlat: function(item, idx, offset){
        var x = idx * this.gap,
            ix = x + offset,
            transf = "";
        if(ix < this.threshold && ix >= - this.threshold){
            // Changing the translation to Y-axis
            transf = "translate3d( 0, "+x+"px, 150px)";
            this.selectedIndex = idx;
        }else if(ix > 0){
            transf = "translate3d("+(x+this.delta)+"px, 0, 0)";
        }else{
            transf = "translate3d("+(x-this.delta)+"px, 0, 0)";
        }
        item.dom.style.webkitTransform = transf;
    },


    doRefresh: function(me){
        console.log("doRefresh Called");
        var container = me.container,
            items, idx = 0, l,
            orientation = Ext.Viewport.getOrientation();

        this.setOrientationCls(orientation);

        this.callParent([me]);

        items = container.getViewItems();
        l = items.length;

        this.itemBox = this.getBaseItemBox(this.element.getBox());
        this.setBoundaries(this.itemBox);

        for(;idx<l;idx++){
            this.resizeItem(items[idx]);
        }

        this.setSelectedIndex(this.selectedIndex);

        // Refresh the horizontal cover flow 
        this.refreshHorizontalCover();
    },

        refreshHorizontalCover: function(){
            console.log("refreshHorizontalCover Called");
        //var container = me.container,
            var hitems, hidx = 0, hl;
           // orientation = Ext.Viewport.getOrientation();

        //this.setOrientationCls(orientation);

        //this.callParent([me]);

        hitems = this.getHorizontalStore().data.items;
        hl = hitems.length;

        this.itemBox = this.getBaseItemBox(this.element.getBox());
        this.setBoundaries(this.itemBox);

        for(;hidx<hl;hidx++){
            var item =  document.createElement("div"); 
            var newContent = document.createTextNode(hitems[hidx].data.preferredName); 
              item.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 
            this.resizeHorizontalItem(item);
        }

        this.setSelectedIndex(this.selectedIndex);

    },

    resizeItem: function(element){
        console.log("resizeItem Called");
        var itemBox = this.itemBox,
            item = Ext.get(element);

        item.setBox(itemBox);
        /**
            itemBox has an extra long in height to avoid reflection opacity over other items
            I need to create a wrapper element with same bg to avoid that issue.
        */
        item.down('.'+this.getItemBaseCls()).setBox({height: itemBox.height/1.5, width: itemBox.width});
    },

    resizeHorizontalItem: function(element){
        console.log("resizeHorizontalItem Called");
        var itemBox = this.itemBox,
            item = Ext.get(element);


        item.setBox(itemBox);
        /**
            itemBox has an extra long in height to avoid reflection opacity over other items
            I need to create a wrapper element with same bg to avoid that issue.
        */
        //item.down('.'+this.getItemBaseCls()).setBox({height: itemBox.height/1.5, width: itemBox.width});
    },

    //override
    onStoreUpdate: function(store, record, newIndex, oldIndex) {
        var me = this,
            container = me.container,
            item;
        oldIndex = (typeof oldIndex === 'undefined') ? newIndex : oldIndex;

        if (oldIndex !== newIndex) {
            container.moveItemsToCache(oldIndex, oldIndex);
            container.moveItemsFromCache([record]);
        }
        else {
            item = container.getViewItems()[newIndex];
            // Bypassing setter because sometimes we pass the same record (different data)
            container.updateListItem(record, item);
            me.resizeItem(item);

        }
    }
});
```

Idea here is to have two cover flows, one horizontal and other vertical intersecting in middle. I can display one cover flow, but the other one is not getting displayed ( or is out of view). Since for one cover I can use properties from DataView , displaying the first is relatively easier than the second. I could help some suggestion on how to display the second.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Data View in Ext is bound to *one* store. I think that much less coding would be to take two views and put them in a layout.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.If it was not clear enough, my question was on how to bind two stores in one view.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. Therefore I advise your custom component would contain two views each bound to its store wrapped in a layout. For the outside world it would be one component but it would use two views internally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it looks okay. The only problem is at the center where the two views are intersecting, From there the user should be able to travel in both the directions( swipe up/ down or right/left ). Is there a way I can pass on the events to the underlying view ?

Comment: I haven't done that so only guess: Could you listen to events on the container, not on views?

Comment: I solved it by passing the event to the underlying view. Thank you for offering your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Super I'm glad you sorted it out. Accept the answer please, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by super-imposing two separate views on top of each other and passing on the event from the top view to the underlying view when the drag was on a particular direction.